# When can MemberExpression.Expression be null?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I wrote a simple utility method that accepts a lambda expression of the form `x => x.PropertyName`, and I want to validate that the expression is indeed of the correct form (the method then does something with the expression which is unrelated to the question). Generally I wrote the code (and unit tests) and it seems I can correctly determine whether the expression is in the correct form or not, but there's one thing I have a doubt about:

I see that [`MemberExpression.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.expression?view=net-7.0) is declared nullable (`Expression?`), but I couldn't think of any case where it could be **null**, and therefore I can't determine whether it's a valid case I should support, or not. What expression would cause `MemberExpression.Expression` to be null?

Comment: I don't believe linq expressions have been updated to account for nullable reference types or any of the more recent additions to the language. I think you're just seeing a symptom of that. Under normal circumstances, I don't believe it would be null.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!
If the expression is an access to a *static* property, like this: `x => MyClass.MyStaticProperty`. In this case `MemberExpression.Expression` will be null.